# How would I check if a letter was in a random word?

Tags: python, random, boolean

I am creating a game, and it entails picking a random word from a list, then asking the user for a letter input. I have this. I now need to check if the letter input is in the random word. How would I do this? I don't have Python on my computer so I can't check if my code works until tomorrow(this is a school project so to check my code I use the school computers). I'm not exactly sure where to start with this, so any guidance would be much appreciated, as I am fairly new to Python(as you may have guessed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a word (variable `word`), you've got a letter (variable `letter`), so go with a simple test to ask if a letter is in the word:

```
if letter in word:
    print('Yes, {} is in the word'.format(letter))  # or whatever message/outcome you want 
else:
    print ('Nope, not there.')
```

That's about it - you can add this in to your existing code, change variable names to match what you have, etc.

Comment: That simple, huh? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For simple coding problems, you can use an online repl: https://repl.it/languages/python3 
Python on your computer without having to install it!